# Transpose rows from excel to word

Tags: excel

I have a Excel sheet with records like name , email , date of birth , mobile , education. I use to copy one record and paste it in word (in transpose mode - to make it look like a resume )
Doing it manually for many records is not feasible - take too much time .How can i automate this process ?

  Any help on this issue is appreciated

Comment: You should create a VBA macro to copy data from one application (Excel) and paste it transposed into the other application (Word). After you achieve this for 1 row, you just have to loop through all your rows.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Can u share any example  ?

Comment: can you at least share what you had tried? at least we know where to start.